# Resource access denied when pushing container to Azure Container Registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, devops, azure-container-registry

When pushing containers into a private Azure Container Registry using Docker Compose the Azure DevOps pipeline returns the following error:

> Pushing [container] ([registry]/[app]:latest)...
>
> The push refers to repository [docker.io/[registry]/[container]]
>
> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

The `azure-pipeline.yml` file is taken from the Docker Compose example shown in the Microsoft Microservices eShopOnContainer example, [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/build/azure-devops/basket-api/azure-pipelines.yml):

```
variables:
azureContainerRegistry: myregistry
azureSubscriptionEndpoint: My Service Principle
...
task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: Compose push customer API
    inputs:
        containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
        azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
        dockerComposeCommand: 'push [container]'
        dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
        qualifyImageNames: true
        projectName: ""
        dockerComposeFileArgs: |
           TAG=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

The service principle is in the [AcrPush role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles).

Comment: Do you try to set the [Content trust for build and push Docker images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/content-trust?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: I'm only using a standard plan for the ACR in Azure, so that's disabled by default. Great shout, thought that could have been it!

Comment: Maybe you can try it. Hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to be explicit with the container name. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops#container-registry-types) is misleading as it states firstly that: the `containerregistrytype` is **Azure Container Registry** by default. The example goes on to give **Contoso** as the value for `azureContainerRegistry`.

This is wrong. You need to explicitly set this to the "Login server" value from Azure. Therefore the registry should be "contoso.azurecr.io". So the full example *should* be:

```
variables:
azureContainerRegistry: contoso.azurecr.io
azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Contoso
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: Container registry login
  inputs:
      containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
      azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
```

This is why the push repo it was referring to was in fact: docker.io (public docker hub) as that must actually be the default whch explains the access denied error.

Comment: To be explicit. Not only do you need to include the full login server name (`contoso.azurecr.io`) you must include the `containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry`. By defualt to get dockerhub, not ACR.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem from `Azure` pipeline. I missed to add `docker-id` in repository section.

From `Azure`, while pushing, if name alone is used e.g. `<repo-name>`, may not work. It need fully qualified repo name which also include `docker-id`.

Use

```
repository: '<docker-id>/<repo-name>'
```

instead of

```
repository: '<repo-name>'
```

Pipeline snippet:

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'service-connection-name'
    repository: '<docker-id>/<repo-name>'
```

Comment: How to find the `docker-id` in Azure?

Comment: you have an equivalent Azure repository.