# Request access denied when trying to push to azure container registry from azure dev ops

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

keep getting this error when I try and push to azure container registry which I have connected up in the 'service connections' as 'containerregistry'

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  azureContainerRegistry: containerregistry
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: resourcemanager

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: DockerCompose@0
      displayName: Build services
      inputs:
        action: Build services
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
        azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
        dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
        projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
        qualifyImageNames: true
        additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
    - task: DockerCompose@0
      displayName: Push services
      inputs:
       action: Push services
       azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
       azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
       dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
       projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
       qualifyImageNames: true
       additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
       includeLatestTag: true
```

the build will work fine but when it tries to push the image i get the following

> [command]/usr/bin/docker push csym023container/csym023_api
>
> The push refers to repository [docker.io/csym023container/csym023_api]
>
> e7a7b94f6564: Preparing
>
> ....etc.....
>
> 2c6ac8e5063e: Waiting
>
> denied: requested access to the resource is denied
>
> [error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied
>
> [error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
>
> [section]Finishing: Push services

[full debug output](https://pastebin.com/24z2xYyb)

It looks like it's trying to push to docker.io for some reason, I did read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421635/resource-access-denied-when-pushing-container-to-azure-container-registry) that you need the login URL which I did try but then I get an error about authorization which I don't know how to implement in the pipeline file.

> [command]/usr/bin/docker push csym023.azurecr.io/csym023_api
>
> The push refers to repository [csym023.azurecr.io/csym023_api]
>
> f29018588af0: Preparing
>
> ...etc ...
>
> cc967c529ced: Waiting
>
> unauthorized: authentication required
>
> [error]unauthorized: authentication required
>
> [error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
>
> [section]Finishing: Push services

[full debug output](https://pastebin.com/U85w189M)

Comment: Could you update with detailed error message about the authorization? Also, better with sharing the sample of your script(compose, dockerfile), and the complete push log?  It's abnormal that the task is pushing to docker.io instead of to azurecr.io, and we did not mentioned this in our document. If this indeed a mislead, I will let the corresponding team know that and made some change.

Comment: I have added the authorization error logs from dev ops, how could I share a sample of my scripts? I did include all the logs I could see on my end but cut out the duplicates ("waiting" / "preparing") but can add them if they are important to debugging.

Comment: You can import it into a third party, then share the link here. It's much better if you can set system.debug=true and share this full log. I think it would be necessary to analyze from it to know the account, the server host it is accessing and how it compile.

Comment: I tried to send an email but it bounced back, I would share but I'm still learning how to work docker/azure so not sure where to set "system.debug=true". but can share my docker-compose.yml, azure-pipelines.yml, and my dockerfiles if that will help

Comment: You can click **Variables**. Then add variable, `system.debug` is the variable name, and `true` is its value. It would be much helpful if you can share those file, because I can try to reproduce and then analyze it on my side. Will delete my email account for security, maybe caused by I am not in your domain so bounced back.

Comment: here is the project project files [wetransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/91d8b32b1c2ff25a275837aa71e8a33c20191115125528/0e8a93) will run a pipeline with the debug variable and update the question when complete.

Comment: For first error you faced(https://pastebin.com/24z2xYyb), see line 56. Here it is trying to connect to this `containerregistry`. If I'm not wrong, this should not be the one of azure, right? If yes, this should be why it is access docker.io later.  How do you configure the task in YAML? Please follow my screenshots(https://imgur.com/a/n8hzQz1), re-configure your task and re-run the pipeline. NOTE: Here is suggesting you troubleshoot the first error, for the solution you found in another thread, annotate it temporary.

Comment: this did solve my issue so thank you, from here I assume I can make an app service on azure and edit it to use the images I have stored on the container registry? a bit unsure what you mean by annotating the other thread though.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it make your builds successfully now. Haven't explained too much in the previous comment because of the words limit. I have already written this worked solution and the explanation of why suggest this solution in the answer below. Please check it  and  appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which can also help others who has same puzzle with you in the community.

Comment: In addition, I work for Azure Devops team, not very familiar with Azure. But based on my experience, **yes, of course you can apply your image into Azure app service**. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed log sharing.

Based on your YAML script and the error log:

[image]

Seem you did configure the task by yourself with specifying the **container registry** value as variable. This should be the cause of why it connected to `docker.io` instead of to `***.azurecr.io` later.

Because the server could not know the correct target container and then be mislead. Also, the identity to Azure Container registry does not available for docker container. At this time, the server prompt the error: `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

---

If use the configure panel we provided in the YAML, the **Azure Container registry** name will display automatically after you select the corresponding **subscription connection**:

[image]

See the value of `azureContainerRegistry`:

```
{"loginServer":"merlin1115.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/daae*****9d072825/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/merlin1115"}
```

You can see that, we provide the exactly target Azure Container Registry name and its unique id. At this time, the server would not confused about which server it should connect to. Meanwhile it can generate the correct **token** which would be used during later **action**(push and etc).

---

The solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421635/resource-access-denied-when-pushing-container-to-azure-container-registry) you found, for `azureContainerRegistry`, @Ste specified its value as `***.azurecr.io`. This similar with the way I mentioned above. Not sure why you faced the **Unauthorized** error when you apply @Ste's solution.

There's no problem on @Ste's solution. Just, when you specify the **container** value by yourself, the **token** generated, has a lot of uncertainty, which would be verified as unreasonable when it needs to be used in later actions.

This is why I suggest you annotated that solution **temporary** when you tried to apply my way.