# Denied: retrieving permissions failed in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my Azure DevOps pipeline to build a container.

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '...'
  imageRepository: '$(project)'
  containerRegistry: $(ACRLoginServer)
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DOCKERFILE'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  azureContainerRegistry: azukschishinyacrd1.azurecr.io
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: azukschishinyacrd1
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    condition: not(eq('${{ variables.imageRepository }}', ''))
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        command: 'login'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          latest
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'azukschishinyacrd1'
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        command: 'push'
```

The DOCKERFILE has this line at the beginning

```
FROM myacrd1.azurecr.io/cellorbase:latest
```

When DevOps runs this line, I get the error

> Error response from daemon: Head https://***/v2/cellorbase/manifests/latest: denied: retrieving permissions failed
>
> Step 1/22 : FROM ***/cellorbase:latest
>
> Head https://***/v2/cellorbase/manifests/latest: denied: retrieving permissions failed
>
> ##[error]Head https://***/v2/cellorbase/manifests/latest: denied: retrieving permissions failed
>
> ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

[image]

Basically, I can't pull an image from the Azure Container Registry but I can push an image to it via the pipeline.

In the `Settings` under `Service Connection` I have connected and granted access permissions to all pipelines.

[image]

I saw other posts on Stackoverflow (for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867554/request-access-denied-when-trying-to-push-to-azure-container-registry-from-azure)) but it is about push an image not to pull an image.

Do you have any idea how can I pull an image from Azure Container Registry avoiding errors?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and the solution. Basically, I have to use **Docker Compose** instead of using the **Azure Container Repository Login**.

[image]

I wrote a step-by-step solution on this [link](https://www.puresourcecode.com/tools/azure-tools/pull-docker-image-from-acr-in-pipelines/).